# ValueError: column_name: <Name> input_tensor dtype must be string or integer. dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, supervised-learning

[supervised classification] I'm trying to train a model with lots of different categorical data with tensorflow and keras. I can't go with One-Hot-Encoding, because there are hundreds of different values.
Therefore I've tried creating a `feature_columncategorical_column_with_hash_bucket` and then turning it into a `feature_column.embedding_column` 
So the string values from my data are beeing transformed into an integer number and then into a 3-Dimensional float Vector. 
When training I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: in converted code:
    relative to C:\Users\kremer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column:

    feature_column_v2.py:474 call
        self._state_manager)
    feature_column_v2.py:3121 get_dense_tensor
        transformation_cache, state_manager)
    feature_column_v2.py:3488 get_sparse_tensors
        transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager), None)
    feature_column_v2.py:2562 get
        transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
    feature_column_v2.py:3466 transform_feature
        return self._transform_input_tensor(input_tensor)
    feature_column_v2.py:3444 _transform_input_tensor
        prefix='column_name: {} input_tensor'.format(self.key))
    utils.py:58 assert_string_or_int
        '{} dtype must be string or integer. dtype: {}.'.format(prefix, dtype))

    ValueError: column_name: Artikel input_tensor dtype must be string or integer. dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>.
```

Here is my Code:

```
#defining feature columns:

feature_columns = []

# numeric cols
for header in ['POS', 'DAUER_RUEST', 'UNTERBRECHUNGEN_RUEST', 'DAUER_PROD', 'UNTERBRECHUNGEN_PROD', 'GUTTEILE', 'Teile_Soll', 'Stueckzeit', 'Ruestzeit_Soll']:
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header))

# categorical columns with embedding
artikel = feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key='Artikel' , hash_bucket_size=600, dtype=tf.dtypes.string)
artikel_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(artikel, dimension=3)
feature_columns.append(artikel_embedding)

batchnumber = feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key='BA' , hash_bucket_size=600, dtype=tf.dtypes.string)
batchnumber_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(batchnumber, dimension=3)
feature_columns.append(batchnumber_embedding)

...

#five embedding columns with this design in total

...

#building and training the model

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(feature_layer)
model.add(layers.Dense(28, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(28, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3)

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=5,
          callbacks=[early_stopping],
          verbose = 1,
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing the following versions:
Tensorflow: 2.1.0
numpy: 1.18.1
pandas: 1.0.3
Python: 3.6.10

Answer (score -1):

change

`artikel = feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key='Artikel' , hash_bucket_size=600, dtype=tf.dtypes.string)` to

`artikel = feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key='Artikel' , hash_bucket_size=600, dtype=tf.dtypes.float)`

Because you define artikel as `string` in categorical_column_with_hash_bucket.
Althrough I'm not familiar with Keras, I think in your `model.fit` ,`artikel` in `train_ds`  is a instance of float.
In tensorflow estimator,`tf.estimator.TrainSpec` input_fn need specific dtype.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The datatype of the elements of the Artikel column is `tf.int64`. Changing my code acording to your suggestion sadly did'nt work eather. 
I Think the problem could be the shape of my tensor. When i type `print(train_ds)`, I get `(?, )` as the result vor Artikel and all the others, too.